# How to train a neural network without lots of labelled data

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, autoencoder

I'm new to machine learning and I'm trying to build a object detection neural network.

I have 3000 images but only 150 are labelled.
My images are composed of web ui pages where I label buttons and logos.

For now, I have tried to train it using the faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_coco model but the results are not great.
The features are found but not perfectly where they need to be.
[image]

Is there a way to improve results? maybe with another model?

If I use an auto-encoder for unsupervised training with all the 3000 images and then use transfer learning into a deep learning model with the labelled data will I get better results? If so, how can I implement it using python with tensorflow?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/).

Comment: That's what gave me those results using the faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_coco model, which model do you think I should use?

Answer (score 1):

First, look into COCO and VOC datasets.

http://cocodataset.org/#home

http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/

If their classes are very similar to yours, then you can take a pre-trained model (deeplab, yolo, maskrnn, etc.) and train on your dataset, the performance should be great. Here are some repositories to check in github:

https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=object+detection&type=Repositories

If your dataset is very different from these, you may not expect good performance. In that case, you have to redesign the network by changing the number of classes. You can use data augmentation (auto-encoder may not be great choice here for data generation as it's complicated to generate good quality images). Here is a good library for data augmentation which augments samples with masks.

https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually for the auto-encoder I was not thinking about generating data but train a first NN on the 3000 non labelled images and then take to weights on the low part of another NN with the labelled data (a pretraining process) so that way the weights are already train to see certains types of pattern what do you think?

Comment: Yes, theoretically works but will take you a good amount of time to generate good quality images, it's easier to use simple augmentation instead.

Comment: Alright, and what about using a lighter CNN? I've read that smaller NN are used for smaller dataset

Comment: yes, obviously you can, but most probably you'll be disappointed. So, you can definitely have a try to observe if the images generated are good enough for your task.